# How to efficiently / correctly handle the click-event at any list-item of a multiple nested list-based menu / navigation?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, selectors-api, event-delegation

Sorry if my question is really for newbie level...

I have a 3 level list to build a menu, but I don't want to use href.
I would like to use a specific attribute instead and call a javascript function with it value.

Here is the markup of my example-list:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#" link_value="item 1">Firts level Menu item 1</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" link_value="item 2-1">Second level Menu item 1</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" link_value="item 3-2-1">Third level Menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" link_value="item 3-2-2">Third level Menu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" link_value="item 3-2-3">Third level Menu item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#" link_value="item 2-2">Second level Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" link_value="item 2-3">Second level Menu item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
<li><a href="#" link_value="item 2">Firts level Menu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" link_value="item 3">Firts level Menu item 3</a></li>
```

How could I run a javascript function to set onclick event for all a items to have something like

```
<a onclick="my_fynction()">
function my_fonction() {do_something(link_value)}
```

and also add an 'active' class to the active element and his parent levels and remove the active class from the others ?

Hope I have been clear enough ?
Many thanks !!!

Comment: Select all of them with `querySelectorAll`, then use `addEventListener` to bind you function to that event on that item?

Comment: FYI, your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `ul` as a direct child of a `ul`. If you want a nested list, you have to put your inner `ul` inside a `li`.

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation

Comment: Another option is make a delegated event on your `.menu` class.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation   mmm, just noticed MDN's hash links don't work in Chrome, but seem fine in Firefox..

Comment: @jeromebg ... `link_value` is an invalid attribute name. Please consider making use of a [`data-*` global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and the DOM element's related [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead ... something like e.g ... `<a href="#" data-value="item 3"/>` where each value then can be read like this ... `linkElement.dataset.value`.

Comment: @jeromebg ... the nested `<ul/>` markup is broken/invalid as well ... please fix it.

Comment: @jeromebg ... The OP might have a look at a late provided, and in detail explained answer. The requirements of the OP are much broader than what could be covered in a quick and short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to clicks on `ul.menu` and put your event logic only on this element.

```
document.querySelector('ul.menu').addEventListener('click', event => {
    // event.target is clicked element
    if(event.target.tagName!=="A") return;
    // prevent default behaviour; redirecting
    event.preventDefault();
    // your code...
})
```

But you'd need to be careful if you put `<span>` for example inside `<a>`. You'd need to put CSS `pointer-events: none;` on these elements.

Comment: An easier option, rather than `pointer-events`, just do ->  `if (!event.target.closest('a')) return;` instead.   Or even more specific -> `if (!event.target.closest('[link_value]')) return;`

Comment: @Keith Yeah, that's an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding both of my above comments ...

> @jeromebg ... `link_value` is an invalid attribute name. Please consider making use of a [`data-*` global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and the DOM element's related [`dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead ... something like e.g ... `<a href="#" data-value="item 3"/>` where each value then can be read like this ... `linkElement.dataset.value`.

> @jeromebg ... the nested `<ul/>` markup is broken/invalid as well ... please fix it.

... and after having fixed the markup, one should make use of, as already suggested but not explicitly named, [event-delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

The latter does not only mean listening at a common (outer) root node, it also means targeting the element/s of interest  which, like the root-node, might have child element-nodes as well.

Thus one always has to query the element/s one is interested in. One mostly does achieve the result by utilizing the [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method of the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)'s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) element.

And regarding another of the OP's requirements ...

> ... also add an 'active' class to the active element and his parent levels and remove the active class from the others ?

... the handler function would pass the currently identified link-element to a custom implemented function, thus forwarding such a special task and not taking care of such stuff by itself.

A function which marks the current menu item has to do following ...

- identifying the menu-item node ... done by ...

  ```
  const menuItem = elmLink.closest('li');
  ```
- identifying the menu-root node ... done by ...

  ```
  const menuRoot = menuItem.closest('ul.menu');
  ```
- choosing the right selector for querying any list-item node which has a link-element (e.g. `'li:has(a[href])'`) and removing the intended class-name (and/or e.g. [aria attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes)) from each queried element.
- adding the intended class-name (and/or e.g. aria attributes) to the list-item which has been identified as *current*.

It is not necessary to mark any list-item involved in another list-item's *current* state as *current* as well. The visual representation of such a state can be easily achieved by utilizing a functional CSS pseudo-class like [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

```js
function markCurrentMenuItem(elmLink) {
  const menuItem = elmLink.closest('li');
  const menuRoot = menuItem.closest('ul.menu');

  menuRoot
    .querySelectorAll('li:has(a[href])')
    .forEach(elm => {

      // elm.classList.remove('active');
      elm.removeAttribute('aria-current');
    });
  // menuItem.classList.add('active');
  menuItem.setAttribute('aria-current', 'true');
}
document
  .querySelector('ul.menu')
  .addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const elmLink = evt.target.closest('a[href][data-value]')

    if (elmLink) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      markCurrentMenuItem(elmLink);

      console.log({ value: elmLink.dataset.value });
    }
  })
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
li { padding: 2px 0 2px 0; }

a span { display: inline-block; padding: 0 20px; background-color: #f2ffa7; }

/* li.active, */li[aria-current="true"] a > span {
  background-color: #b1d000;
}
/* ul:has(> li.active), */ul:has(> li[aria-current="true"]) {
  background-color: #bee8ff;
}
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu" role="menu" aria-label="Main Menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-value="item 1">
      <span>First level Menu item 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul role="menu" aria-label="Second Level Menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="item 2-1">
          <span>Second level Menu item 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul role="menu" aria-label="Third Level Menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-value="item 3-2-1">
              <span>Third level Menu item 1</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-value="item 3-2-2">
              <span>Third level Menu item 2</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-value="item 3-2-3">
              <span>Third level Menu item 3</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="item 2-2">
          <span>Second level Menu item 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-value="item 2-3">
          <span>Second level Menu item 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-value="item 2">
      <span>First level Menu item 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-value="item 3">
      <span>First level Menu item 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```