# addclass also to parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, closest

I'm building a multi level menu and would like to add an active class to the element through a function (which is working) but would also want to add this class to it parents elements.

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 1</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_1">Scene 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_2">Scene 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 2</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_3">Scene 3</a></li>
            <ul>
            <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_3.1">Scene 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_3.2">Scene 3.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" scene="scene_4">Scene 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the function :

```
function set_active_scene(name){
    $("ul.main-menu ul li a").each(function() {
        $(this.closest('li')).removeClass("active");
        if ($(this).attr("scene") == name)
            $(this.closest('li')).addClass("active");
    });
}
```

I tried with `$(this.parents('li')).addClass("active");` but it's not working.
Any idea ?

Comment: Which parent element are you trying to update?

Comment: Typo: `this.parents()` uses DOM parents() which doesn't exist - **always check the console for errors** (F12).  You probably meant `$(this).parents("li")` which works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/h9r60t8k/

Comment: @jeromebg ... like with [your yesterdays question's example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947915/how-to-efficiently-correctly-handle-the-click-event-at-any-list-item-of-a-mult), the markup of the nested lists is broken and not consistent. What is the reason for insisting on this approach (building a path of `'active'` classified elements into the nested list item hirarchy) when the functional [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) css pseudo-class offers a simpler solution, which is ... having to control the **active** state of just a single list-item.

Comment: @jeromebg ... Regarding your yesterdays problem/question as well ... it also is kind of rude to not provide any feedback on a detailed answer which provides solutions for any of your requirements, but to abandon the thread in favor of opening a new one.

Comment: `scene` is not a valid HTML5 attribute. use `data-scene` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want to add the "active" class to the immediate parent li element of the active anchor element, you can simply use parent(). Here's the modified function:

```
function set_active_scene(name) {
    $("ul.main-menu ul li a").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass("active"); // Remove active class from all list items
        if ($(this).attr("scene") == name) {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass("active"); // Add active class to the current list item
            $(this).parent('li').addClass("active"); // Add active class to the immediate parent list item
        }
    });
}
```

With this modification, only the immediate parent of li element of the active a element will receive the "active" class, not all parent li elements up the DOM tree.

Comment: `$(this).closest("li")` will find the closest parent `<li>` and `$(this).parent("li")` will return the parent if it's an `li`.  Assuming the parent *is* an `li` then they will both give the same, single element.

Answer (score -1):

Like with the OP's yesterdays question ... [*"How to efficiently / correctly handle the click-event at any list-item of a multiple nested list-based menu / navigation?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947915/how-to-efficiently-correctly-handle-the-click-event-at-any-list-item-of-a-mult) ... one first has to fix the broken and inconsistent markup including the invalid `scene` attribute for links.

The OP's originally provided function which has to set an active scene by a provided scene-name then can be refactored towards ...

- allow an additional menu-root node being passed as first parameter which makes the function more generic in terms of how a menu-root has/needs to be queried
- query the targeted link-node by its attribute-related scene-name.
- remove the `active` class-name from any of the menu's list-item nodes, which gets achieved by querying all the menu's list-item nodes and removing said class-name from each of these nodes.
- the main task, the OP is asking for gets achieved by programmatically building kind of a path of as `active` classified list-item nodes from inside-out ... which means always following/accessing the next closest and available list-item node, adding an `active` class-name to each of these nodes.

```js
function setActiveScene(menuRoot, sceneName) {
  // - query the targeted link-node by its attributed scene-name.
  let targetNode = menuRoot.querySelector(`a[data-scene="${ sceneName }"]`);

  // - remove the `active` class-name from
  //   any of the menu's list-item nodes.
  menuRoot
    .querySelectorAll('li')
    .forEach(elmNode => elmNode.classList.remove('active'));


  // - programmatically build a path of `active`
  //   classified list-item nodes from inside-out.
  while (targetNode = targetNode.parentNode.closest('li')) {

    targetNode.classList.add('active');
  }
}

const menuRoot = document.querySelector('ul.main-menu');

setTimeout(setActiveScene, 600, menuRoot, 'scene_3.2');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 2600, menuRoot,'scene_3.1');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 4600, menuRoot, 'scene_3');

setTimeout(setActiveScene, 6600, menuRoot, 'scene_4');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 8600, menuRoot, 'scene_2');
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
li { padding: 2px 0 2px 0; }
a { padding: 0 20px; background-color: #f2ffa7; }
li.active > a { background-color: #b1d000; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 1</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_1">Scene 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_2">Scene 2</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 2</a>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3">Scene 3</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3.1">Scene 3.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3.2">Scene 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_4">Scene 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in case the OP insists on a jQuery based solution (which does not offer any benefit over the standardized [Selectors API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)), the above example code changes to ...

```js
function setActiveScene($menuRoot, sceneName) {
  // - query the targeted link-node by its attributed scene-name.
  let targetNode = $menuRoot.find(`a[data-scene="${ sceneName }"]`)[0];

  // - remove the `active` class-name from
  //   any of the menu's list-item nodes.
  $menuRoot
    .find('li')
    .each((_, elmNode) => $(elmNode).removeClass('active'));


  // - programmatically build a path of `active`
  //   classified list-item nodes from inside-out.
  while (targetNode = targetNode.parentNode.closest('li')) {

    $(targetNode).addClass('active');
  }
}

const $menuRoot = $('ul.main-menu');

setTimeout(setActiveScene, 600, $menuRoot, 'scene_3.2');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 2600, $menuRoot,'scene_3.1');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 4600, $menuRoot, 'scene_3');

setTimeout(setActiveScene, 6600, $menuRoot, 'scene_4');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 8600, $menuRoot, 'scene_1');
setTimeout(setActiveScene, 10600, $menuRoot, 'scene_2');
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
li { padding: 2px 0 2px 0; }
a { padding: 0 20px; background-color: #f2ffa7; }
li.active > a { background-color: #b1d000; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 50%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 1</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_1">Scene 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_2">Scene 2</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Maine Level 2</a>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3">Scene 3</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3.1">Scene 3.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_3.2">Scene 3.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#" class="nav-link" data-scene="scene_4">Scene 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but *possibly* because it was a typo, as *all* provided answers got a -1.  As a personal note, *in my opinion* (only) if comes across as a rant, eg "insists on jQuery".  Finally, FYI,, you can use a simple call to `.parents("li")` instead of the `while` and no need for `.each` with `...find("li").each((_, elmNode) => $(elmNode).removeClass('active')` => `...find("li").removeClass("active")`.  Maybe jQuery's more powerful/useful than you give it credit? ;)  But I suspect it was just broad -1 on all answers.